# Using view pager in recycler view row?

Tags: android, view, fragment, pager

In my app, I am using a fragment view pager in my recycler view rows. I am doing this to display the main content in the first fragment and then a fragment container a delete button as the second fragment. For some reason, when I launch my app, my view pager is only working in the first row. Does anyone know what could be causing this? I have tried using multiple static rows, but it only works in the first one. This is my recycler view adapter code:

- It may be important to note that the view which this recycler view is contained in is part of another view pager which is located inside a fragment.

  ```
  public class FeaturesListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeaturesListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  public static final int NULL = -1;

  public static final int NUMBER_OF_FEATURES = 2;

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

      RelativeLayout root;
      ViewPager viewPager;

      public ViewHolder(RelativeLayout container, SampleActivity activity) {
          super(container);

          root = container;
          viewPager = (ViewPager) container.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
          viewPager.setAdapter(new FeatureCellPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), activity));
          viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
      }
  }

  final SampleActivity mActivity;

  public FeaturesListAdapter(SampleActivity activity) {
      mActivity = activity;
  }

  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_features_list, viewGroup, false);
      return new ViewHolder((RelativeLayout) view, mActivity);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      return NULL;
  }


  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      return NUMBER_OF_FEATURES;
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: You say your recyclerView and fragments are contained in another fragment, I think you have to use getChildFragmentManager() then. So instead of new FeatureCellPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), activity)); try it with new FeatureCellPagerAdapter(yourOuterFragment.getChildFragmentManager(), activity));

Comment: I saw this immediately after posting, though I just tried it and it didn't work

Comment: I also tried adding like 20 views, and it applies a viewpager to the first visible fragment but not all of them..

Comment: Yeah I just tested this and I get the same results, only the first row has a viewpager with fragments in it. And I don't have the outer fragment, so this is not the cause.

Comment: could it be a problem with my xml?

Comment: I got the same problem. Have you resolved it yet @TeddyWilson ?

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this problem and resolve this by set ID for each ViewPager :)

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks for the solution! :)